# SQL запрос к двум таблицам

Tags: sql, запрос, mysql

Добрый день. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с запросом. Ситуация такова: в базе имеется 2 таблицы с одинаковыми полями. К примеру, в таблице `Table1` есть поле `NAME`, и в `Table2` есть поле `NAME`. Каким образом можно вывести те строки из таблицы Table1, у которых значение поля `NAME` совпадает со значением поля `NAME` у `Table2`?
Пытался вывести таким образом:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE name = (SELECT name FROM table2)
```

Не работает, ибо подзапрос возвращает несколько строк, а не одну.
Как быть?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Почитайте что такое `inner` и `left/right join`'ы. В вашем случае надо что-то типа такого:

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.* FROM table1 
  inner join TABLE2 on table1.name=table2.name
```

P.S. Могу чутка ошибиться в синтаксисе - давно не сиквелил :)

Comment: Спасибо. Это работает. Обидно, что не сам додумался =(

Answer (score 2):

Про джоины всё правильно, но всё же предложу два альтернативных варианта:

1: SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE name IN (SELECT name FROM table2);

2: SELECT a.*, b.* FROM table1 a, table2 b WHERE a.name = b.name;